# height not resized when using flexbox under reacts

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to do this in a react App:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4gctqv2/1/

but while it works in the example link, in the react app the heights are not resized.

The App renders return:

```
return (
      <div className="row0">
        <div className="row1"><p>1</p></div>
        <div className="row2"><p>2</p></div>
        <div className="row3"><p>3</p></div>
      </div>
    );
```

The CSS code of the example is linked in the App.css. In fact, the background colors are applied.

Is there anything different that should be done to make it work in react?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a root element that your react app is placed inside of.  Make sure in your css you set that element to have a height of 100% as well.  Remember to use heights in percentage every parent element must have a 100% height as well.  So inspect your app with developer tools and make sure all of your parent elements have a height of 100%.